# if statement count number of working days from date, and flag any dates older than 10 working days

Tags: excel, formula, days

I am using the following excel formula to try and check if a date is older than 10 working days and if it is display the text "Chase" else if the date is within 10 working days count the number of working days.

I have a date in my cell N11: `25/07/2015`
and then I have the following formula in my cell U11:

```
=IF(N11>TODAY()-NETWORKDAYS(10),CONCATENATE(NETWORKDAYS(N11,TODAY())," Working Days"),"Chase")
```

Please can someone show me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Please update your question by adding the description of your problem. Do you get an error message, does it not work as you expect? If you want to check for dates older than 10 working days then you need to check `NETWORKDAYS(N11,TODAY())>10` instead of `N11>TODAY()-10`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that `NETWORKDAYS` returns your expected value (count...), use it in the `IF`:

```
=IF(NETWORKDAYS(N11,TODAY())<=10,CONCATENATE(NETWORKDAYS(N11,TODAY())," Working Days"),"Chase")
```